# Elasticsearch endpoint as public api

Tags: elasticsearch

I created new elasticsearch and exposed it publicly on port 9200

I do not want use any authorization publicly so i want to only "SELECT" operation can be done via public host. 
In other word i want to block any "INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE" operations on public host but this operations should be done still on "localhost". How can i configure this?

Is this common practice and is this save to expose elasticsearch endpoint directly publicly? I do not want use any middleware api that affect response speed.

Comment: If you put a reverse proxy, like nginx, in front the elasticsearch to proxypass only the `/search` location, it would not impact the response time.